# PHP parse html and change links

Tags: php, html

I'm creating a proxy server with PHP, and i was wondering if it were possible to convert links (both relative and absolute) to absolute URLS and then change the links so that they go to a place on my website. Its hard to explain, but this is essentially what i want

```
<html>
<body>
 <a href='http://www.google.com'>This is a link</a><br><br>
 <a href='/index.php'>This is another</a><br>
 <form action='/act.php'>
   <input type='submit'>
 </form>
```

Which i would get using

```
file_get_contents("http://www.thiswebsite.com")
```

The intended output would be

```
     <html>
<body>
 <a href='proxy.php?url=http://www.google.com'>This is a link</a><br><br>
 <a href='proxy.php?url=http://www.thiswebsite.com/index.php'>This is another</a><br>
 <form action='proxy.php?url=http://www.thiswebsite.com/act.php'>
   <input type='submit'>
 </form>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You could try using the PHP DOMDocument API. You would write something like:

```
<?php
$document = file_get_contents("http://www.thiswebsite.com");
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($document);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$anchors = $xpath->query("//a[@href]");
foreach( $anchors as $anchor) {
    $href = $anchor->getAttribute("href");
    $your_site_prefix = "proxy.php?url=";
    $anchor->setAttribute("href", $your_site_prefix . $href);
}

echo $xpath->document->saveHTML();
?>
```